# Why receiving "Access is denied" error message when trying to modify Windows Registry using "Registry Finder" application?

Tags: windows, windows-7, permissions, windows-registry, administrator

In the [Registry Finder application](https://registry-finder.com/) (a third-party tool), I am receiving "Access is denied. (5)." error messages when trying to perform a bulk search and replace of the Windows registry on a Win7 box.

Specifically, the errors are all of the form:

```
Modify value HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Test\ - Access is denied. (5)
Modify value HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Test\ - Access is denied. (5)
```

Before performing the operation, I logged in as Admin and ran Registry Finder as administrator.

Why is this error likely appearing, and what can be done to perform the operation without errors?

Comment: Have you confirmed you get the same behavior on a fresh installation of Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound No, but I can.  What could make a difference?